# Router admin page not reachable through WAN port

Tags: networking, router, lan, tcpip, wan

Let us say , I have a home router which have

```
LAN port : 192.168.0.1
WAN port : 10.137.141.195
```

Now , When I do `192.1768.0.1:80` , I am able to open the admin page but when I do `10.137.141.195:80` , I am not able to do it. Why ?

EDIT : This is how my home router is :

```
                WAN
                |
                |
                |
                |
            Router 1 (my ISP Set it up)
            /              \
           /                \
          /                 My Router (It is connected by WAN port to Router 1)
        Some connection1     |
                             |
                             |
                             My computer (connected at LAN)
```

Comment: Are you trying to open this page from inside or outside of your local network?

Comment: @DavidPostill  From inside I tried to open , but I am curious to open it from outside too but for that I don't have access . :)

Comment: Accessing the router public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: @DavidPostill , I have added more details. Please have a look. In this scenario , I dnt think we need NAT hairpinning. In short , it is behind another router set up by ISP in my building and each person buys a connection from them.

Comment: I disagree.......

Comment: @DavidPostill , you are correct except that even if the router is behind another router as in my case , it gets a private ip and we still need NAT Hairpinning. One question though : When the ip packet leaves my router towards ISP router (as shown in image) , then that packet ip will be `10.137.141.195` or `my laptop ip` ? i mean does most home router have a NAT table inbuilt in it ? I have [TpLink-TL-WR841N](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/326021/Tp-Link-Tl-Wr841n.html?page=5#manual) and it does support port triggering , virtual server , DMZ etc

Comment: I mean if I connect my laptop to `router 1 by ISP` and directly hit  `my computer private ip` , it would have connected it , if `my home router in between` did not had NAT table feature enabled by default ?

Comment: @DavidPostill Your link 404's (and throws a cert error).

Comment: Opening your router’s configuration page up to the internet is a terrible idea. I know this doesn’t answer your question. But these cheap, home devices have firmware so full of holes, some Russian or Chinese hacker group will own that router in a matter of hours and you probably won’t know a thing.

Comment: @MichaelKolber Archive link here [What is NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need several things for this to work, and all of them are unavailable or not well defined on a consumer router

- NAT Hair-pinning. The router needs to understand that you are using it as a NAT gateway, but you want an internal resource. This probably isn't an option.
- Depending on how your router handles 'local' traffic, you may need to enable the Admin portal from the WAN side. The admin portal is probably disabled by default on the WAN side for security reasons. 'Local' traffic is traffic arriving to the router that is destine for any IP address owned by the router. It is usually subject to special rules.
- Port forward port 80 to the router's LAN IP.

Try all of these. You might get lucky.

Note: Do not do either of the latter two things on an internet exposed router. Its a major security issue.